# When the main body calls for a constructor, the constructor calls for a function and when it does tries to call for a function it crashes?

Tags: c++

After the constructor is called in the body, the constructor calls for the function and that's when my program crashes. I can't find the reason why...thanks in advance.

There may be other logical  errors in the code but I'm currently trying to figure out the reason why it won't call the function from constructor. I'm pretty sure I've set it up correctly but it still crashes.

This program is for an assignment for my class.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Rational
{
public:
    //void setNum(int);
    //void setDen(int);

    void gcd(int, int);
    void normalize(int, int, int, bool, bool);
    int getNum();
    int getDen();

    Rational(int num, int den)
    {
        numerator = num;
        denominator = den;
        cout << "i made it through the constgructor now sending it to gcd";
        gcd(numerator, denominator);
    }

    Rational(int wholeNumber)
    {
        wholeNumber = wholeNumber / 1;
    }

    Rational()
    {
        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 1;
    }

private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

};



void Rational::gcd(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int gcd;
    bool negNum;
    bool negDen;

    //check if numerator is negative
    //if so change it before finding gcd
    if (numerator < 0)
    {
        negNum = true;
        numerator = -1 * numerator;
    }
    else
    {
        negNum = false;
    }

    //check if denominator is negative
    //if so change it before finding gcd
    if (denominator < 0)
    {
        negDen = true;
        denominator = -1 * denominator;
    }
    else
    {
        negDen = false;
    }

    //finds the gcd of both numbers
    for (int i = 0; i <= numerator&&denominator; i++)
    {
        if (numerator%i == 0 && denominator%i == 0) //if i divides into both #s evenly then its the gcd so far
        {
            gcd = i;
        }
    }

    //call for normalize function
    normalize(numerator, denominator, gcd, negNum, negDen);
}

void Rational::normalize(int numerator, int denominator, int gcd, bool negNum, bool negDen)
{
    //if numerator was negative make it negative again
    if (negNum = true)
    {
        numerator = -1 * numerator;
    }

    //if denominator was negative make it negative again
    if (negDen = true)
    {
        denominator = -1 * denominator;
    }

    //simplify
    numerator = numerator / gcd;
    denominator = denominator / gcd;

    //if both were negative change them to positive
    if (numerator && denominator < 0)
    {
        numerator = -1 * numerator;
        denominator = -1 * denominator;
    }

    //check if wholeNumber
    /*
    if (numerator / denominator == 0)
    {
        isWhole = true;
        wholeNumber = numerator / denominator;
    }*/
}

/*void Rational::setNum(int numerator)
{
    numerator = numerator;
}*/

int Rational::getNum()
{
    return numerator;
}

int Rational::getDen()
{
    return denominator;
}

int main()
{
    int num, den;
    char slash;

    //Rational f1;
    //Rational f2;
    //Rational f3;

    cout << "Enter a fraction in the format integer_numerator/integer_denominator\n";
    cin >> num >> slash >> den;

    Rational f1(num, den);
    //cout << "sent it off already to constructor\n"; //good
    //f1.gcd(num, den);
    //cout << "sent it to gcd\n";

    cout << "\nYou entered the equivalent of: " << f1.getNum() << "/" << f1.getDen();

    cout << "\nEnter a fraction in the format integer_numerator/integer_denominator\n";
    cin >> num >> slash >> den;
    //put error message here
    //else send it to gcd
    Rational f2(num, den);
    f2.gcd(num, den);

    cout << "\nYou entered the equivalent of: " << f2.getNum() << "/" << f2.getDen();

    cout << "\nEnter a fraction in the format integer_numerator/integer_denominator\n";
    cin >> num >> slash >> den;
    //put error message here
    //else send it to gcd
    Rational f3(num, den);
    f3.gcd(num, den);

    cout << "\nYou entered the equivalent of: " << f3.getNum() << "/" << f3.getDen();
    cout << "\nTesting arithmetic and relational operator overloading\n";

    //display math
    cout << f1.getNum() << "/" << f1.getDen() << " * " << f2.getNum() << "/" << f2.getDen() << " = " << (f1.getNum() / f1.getDen()) * (f2.getNum() / f2.getDen());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ - please try to debug your code on your own before you post it to SO. At the very least you should be able to figure out on which line it crashes

Comment: Which line crashes exactly?

Comment: The error message and your input which cause the crash. Also not all paths assign value to `gcd` in `Rational::gcd` shich is also not inited

Comment: Also `i <= numerator&&denominator` and `if (numerator && denominator < 0)` are strange

Comment: Visual Studio has a very and easy to use debugger. Use it.

Comment: The `Rational(int)` constructor fails to initialize the member variables.

Comment: IMO, it should be considered cheating if no effort is done to debug the code,  even a diagnostic `cout` or `printf` statement, and leave this job for others to debug.  Part of the learning curve in programming is learning how to debug programs that you write yourself.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: When I compile my code I use the Local Windows Debugger so I thought that debugs my program. I've also stated that my program crashes as soon as the constructor calls for the function. I knew that from setting cout in certain spots of code. Couldn't figure out the problem so here I am. thanks for the help all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `gcd` function has a local variable `gcd` that isn't initialized. It is possible for the function to execute through to the `normalize` call without assigning a value to `gcd`. That uninitialized variable's value is then  passed as an argument to `normalize`.

Your loop inside `gcd` starts from `i = 0`. Then `i` is used as a divisor in the loop as in `numerator % i`.  That's a division by zero; `%` calculates the residue of a division, and so is a kind of division operation.

As an aside, you should know about [Euclid's algorithm for GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations).  Also the [Binary GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm#Implementation) which uses only bit operations and shifts.